# Python BeautifulSoup can't read div tag

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get products for a project I'm working on from this page:[lazada](http://www.lazada.co.id/catalog/?q=note%202), 
[page ispection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lR24T.png)
using :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re
r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.lazada.co.id/catalog/?q=note+2").read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r,"lxml")
letters = soup.findAll("span",class_=re.compile("product-card__name"))
print type(letters) 
print letters[0]
```

When I do this I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/project/testaja.py", line 9, in 
    print letters[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: What does `print(r)` output? The code works fine for me.

Comment: This code also works completely fine for me. I suspect that you either do not have access (maybe you scraped it too often and the server blocked you - check if header code is 403) or for some reason the HTML was never sent along.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have hit their page too much, navigate there in a browser and see what the page returns on your network.

Also, you can modify your code so you can check the page response header to make sure that the page returned properly before trying to scrape it. I modified your code to show an example of this below:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib
import re

r = urllib.urlopen("http://www.lazada.co.id/catalog/?q=note+2")
header_code = r.getcode()

if header_code == 200:
    html = r.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    letters = soup.findAll("span", {"class" : re.compile("product-card__name")})

    for letter in letters:
        print letter
else:
    print("oops, something went wonky. Page response was: %s"% header_code)
```

Comment: i try your code and get header code 200 but still cant find the element span it return nothing  any other soution sir ?  btw im using python 2.7.1.1 in windows 8<br> thankyou in advance

Comment: Check to see how I modified the soup findAll in my example, see if that works for you.

Comment: Alright, give it a try now. I didn't realize beautifulsoup 4 uses regex differently than version 3.

Comment: Still no Luck sir, :(  but when i tray to do this to other web ex [link](http://news.detik.com/), its work fine but it still return nothing with [lazada](http://www.lazada.co.id/catalog/?q=note+2)

Comment: Can you make sure the HTML is loading properly for you and it's not some captcha or something similar? I've tested it as is against this page and it returns a whole list of items.

Comment: Everything looks fine in my browser, page load correctly without any captcha i try it in [amazon(http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_1?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=casio+smartwatch) the code work as well,:(